# Duplicate archive subfolders with Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, archive

I have a strange problem with Mail and I cannot understand if it's a bug or not.

When I archive a message, Mail creates duplicated subfolders. They are called "On my Mac" and they are located under "Archive" folder.

All the subfolders, 4 in my case, contain the same message. This is quit strange since if I delete a folder, I cannot find the message anywhere else (i.e. the message is deleted in the other ones).

Here a discussion on Apple forum where it appears to be an unresolved bug:
[Duplicate Mail archive folders](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19123032#19123032).

I'm running ML 10.8.4 and Mail 6.5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the duplicate folder still there when you go off line with mail?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Sorry for the delay. Yes. Non chance to remove that additional folders. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem for quite some time.  I did a completely new install on a brand new machine and still had this problem.  Here was my solution.

Back before Mail had an archiving feature, I had a folder called "Archive" that I used to put mail that matched certain rules.  **The presence of this rule caused a folder to be created with that name.**  This must have cause some electronic version of confusion.

When I removed the rule and deleted the folder one more time, I was left with a single Archive folder.